# Python numpy: don't understand the result of subtracting np.datetime64 dates

Tags: python, numpy, timedelta, datetime64

If I do the following operation:

```
import numpy as np

np.datetime64('20230901') - np.datetime64('20230831')
```

I get the result

```
numpy.timedelta64(70,'Y')
```

I get that the letter 'Y' in this case means Year, but what does the 70 mean?

Furthermore, if I do the same operation specifying a time:

```
import numpy as np

np.datetime64('20230901-01') - np.datetime64('19700101-01')
```

I get the same number but in months:

```
numpy.timedelta64(840,'M')
```

What is the meaning of that amount of years/months?

Comment: Your string `'20230901'` is being interpreted as a year. Try adding hyphens, e.g., `'2023-09-01'` for the proper date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.datetime64`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.datetime64) takes the `YYYY-MM-DD` format as input if you want to specify year-month-day, **the dashes are important**:

```
np.datetime64('2023-09-01') - np.datetime64('2023-08-31')
```

Output: `numpy.timedelta64(1,'D')`

Without them, the strings are interpreted as years, effectively having `20230901-20230831` = `70` years.